# How to correctly use flexible array member?

Tags: c, unions, flexible-array-member

Here is a type I declared:
(I declared `t_sphere`, `t_cylinder` and `t_triangle` too)

```c
typedef struct  s_intersection{
  double       t1;
  double       t2;
  int id;
  union {
    t_sphere sph;
    t_cylinder cyl;
    t_triangle tri;
  } u[];
} t_intersection;
```

To refer to the union variable inside my struct, I have to know in advance what type it is. This is possible thanks to the id int declared in my struct, but it is very heavy to achieve with the method I thought of.
Here is the function I wrote to allocate a t_intersection variable:

```c
t_intersection  *intersection(unsigned int geometric_figure_id, void *figure)
{
    t_intersection  *p;

    if (geometric_figure_id == SPHERE_ID)
        p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + sizeof (p->u[0].sp));
    else if (geometric_figure_id == CYLINDER_ID)
        p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + sizeof (p->u[0].cy));
    else if (geometric_figure_id == TRIANGLE_ID)
        p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + sizeof (p->u[0].tr));
    if (p == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));
    p->id = geometric_figure_id:
    if (geometric_figure_id == SPHERE_ID)
        p->u[0].sp = *(t_sphere *)figure;
    else if (geometric_figure_id == CYLINDER_ID)
        p->u[0].cy = *(t_cylinder *)figure;
    else if (geometric_figure_id == TRIANGLE_ID)
        p->u[0].tr = *(t_triangle *)figure;
    return (p);
}
```

Is there a better way of achieving this?
EDIT: I added the mallocs I forgot + assigning the id...

Comment: Your method should probably copy `geometric_figure_id` to `p->id` so that other methods can tell what type it contains in the union.

Comment: [Before the edit to the question]: You should be allocating memory, but you don't — you assign the size of an object to a 'pointer to intersection' type, which won't compile (without warnings, but you should be treating all warnings as errors anyway).  It's not clear why you're using a FAM if you are only going to assign one element of the array.  You should allocate `malloc(sizeof(*p) + sizeof(p->u));` and it shouldn't be conditioned on the type ID.  Given that you only allocate one element for the array, it would be more sensible just to have the union as a non-array member of the structure.

Comment: This is pseudo-code, right? There's no allocation happening after assigning a `size_t` value to a pointer.... What's this supposed to be?

Comment: Note that if you did ever allocate multiple elements for the union, they must all be the size of the union, not the size of any of the components.  The compiler will index the array by the size of the union, not by the size of the members of the union.  You'd also need to record how many elements are in the FAM.

Comment: The size of the structure depends on the number of elements of `u`, *not* the type of those elements.  In all cases, you want the size of the `union` type (which you should define as an independent type), *not* its members.  Remember, when accessing `u`, the index applies to the union, and is scaled by the size of the union.  It's an array of unions, not a union of arrays as your `malloc` code incorrectly suggests.

Comment: In a previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350057/how-to-correctly-use-flexible-member-array#comment132956596_75350057), I wrote: `malloc(sizeof(*p) + sizeof(p->u));` — that was wrong and should have been `malloc(sizeof(*p) + sizeof(p->u[0]));`.

Comment: `memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p)` is incorrect. You overwrite the pointer itself with zero bytes

Comment: I am not sure if it is well-defined to under-allocate a union object to only the size of the member you intend to use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to always allocate space for the entire union, not just one member.  Also, you can use `calloc` to allocate memory that is zero-initialized.

So you can replace this:

```
if (geometric_figure_id == SPHERE_ID)
    p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + sizeof (p->u[0].sp));
else if (geometric_figure_id == CYLINDER_ID)
    p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + sizeof (p->u[0].cy));
else if (geometric_figure_id == TRIANGLE_ID)
    p = malloc(sizeof(*p) + sizeof (p->u[0].tr));
if (p == NULL)
    return (NULL);
memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));
```

With this:

```
p = calloc(1, sizeof(*p) + sizeof (p->u[0]));
if (p == NULL)
    return (NULL);
```

To simplify even more, since you're only every creating one instance of the union, you don't need a flexible array member.  Just declare your struct like this:

```
typedef struct  s_intersection{
  double       t1;
  double       t2;
  int id;
  union {
    t_sphere sph;
    t_cylinder cyl;
    t_triangle tri;
  };
} t_intersection;
```

And create an instance like this:

```
t_intersection  *intersection(unsigned int geometric_figure_id, void *figure)
{
    t_intersection  *p;

    p = calloc(1, sizeof(*p));
    if (p == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    p->id = geometric_figure_id:
    if (geometric_figure_id == SPHERE_ID)
        p->sp = *(t_sphere *)figure;
    else if (geometric_figure_id == CYLINDER_ID)
        p->cy = *(t_cylinder *)figure;
    else if (geometric_figure_id == TRIANGLE_ID)
        p->tr = *(t_triangle *)figure;
    return (p);
}
```

Comment: When I use that intersection structure in some code, is there a handy way to refer to the member inside my struct ?
e.g. Let's say I want to write a function that acts differently according to the type of geometric_figure```t_intersection *p```contains. Will I have to ```ìf (geometric_figure_id == SPHERE_ID) ... else if ... else``` ? I feel it is very heavy

Comment: @BobDeTunis You can either do that or you can use a `switch` statement.

Answer (score 1):

**Bug**

`memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));` overwrote the pointer just returned form `malloc()`. [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350057/how-to-correctly-use-flexible-array-member/75351220#comment132956874_75350057)

Likely wanted `memset(p, 0, sizeof p[0]);`

**Memory usage**

You can follow [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75350177/2410359) approach and allocate to the size of the [FAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) union in all cases.

When the `.u` member's type is not changed over the life of `p`, code can be more memory efficient.

OP's original approach reduces over-allocating yet could use some improvements.

```
t_intersection *intersection(unsigned geometric_figure_id, const void *figure) {
  assert(geometric_figure_id < ID_N);
  static const size_t fig_size[ID_N] = { 
    [SPHERE_ID]   = sizeof(t_sphere), 
    [CYLINDER_ID] = sizeof(t_cylinder), 
    [TRIANGLE_ID] = sizeof(t_triangle),
  };
  t_intersection *p = malloc(sizeof p[0] + fig_size[geometric_figure_id]);
  if (p) {
    memset(p, 0, sizeof p[0]);
    memcpy(p->u, figure, fig_size[geometric_figure_id]);
  }
  return p;
}
```

**Advanced**

There is another efficiency step discussed [here](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2011/03/14/flexible-array-member/) that uses `offsetof(p, u)` instead of `sizeof p[0]`.